# Получение IP адреса c сервера через wifi AP

Tags: dhcp, wifi, ip

Есть домен, есть сервер DHCP на win 2008 R2, есть wifi AP на D-link DWL-2100AP (DHCP на нем выключен). Некоторые клиенты подключены в сеть через wifi AP, эти клиенты получают IP с сервера, которые зарезервированы для них по MAC адресу.

Проблема: если клиент несколько дней не подключался к сети, то при попытке подлючения он не может получить IP адрес. Если wifi AP перезапустить, то адрес получают без проблем.Логи на сервере ничего не фиксируют. Логи на роутере пишут:

> `Association:11G STA (MAC) associated with WLAN1 SSID = (name)Received Disassoc: WLAN 1 11G STA (MAC)`

Дальше по кругу.

Comment: DWL не висит, через нее работают клиенты, которые включаются ежедневно. У меня таких AP две, на обоих такое, пробовал ставить d-link 615, то же самое.

Comment: Сеть сделана обычно (AD, DNS, DHCP), без сегментов, выход в интернет через TMG, DMZ нет, используются свичи (с стандартными настройками) HP ProCurve 1810G-24, HP ProCurve 1800-24G, HP ProCurve 1800-8G, HP ProCurve 2650.Сниффить не пробовал.

Comment: Да сниферы и не помогут в данной ситуации. Это разные уровни сети.

Comment: Хочешь сказать снифер не увидит запросы ?

Comment: одно дело если запросы не приходят на сервант другое, они приходят но ответа нет.Пишите коменты адресованные мне под моим ответом.

Comment: Извиняюсь что поднял старый вопрос. Хотел бы уточнить у автора решил ли он описанную проблему или нет? Сам столкнулся недавно с такой проблемой...

Answer (score 3):

Может быть тупо висит DWL и трафик не пропускает. Проверьте с статическим ip

Comment: Как устроена сеть ? Что есть в сети кроме АД? Что приходит на dhcp в момент не получения ip(сниф)?

Comment: С помощью MS Network Monitor прослушал сеть в P-mode, в результате:видно что идет широковещательный запрос с клиента и на этот запрос отвечает DHCP сервер, но ответ не доходит до клиента и запрос повторяется.Почему он его не получает остается загадкой, очевидно, ответ теряется где-то в недрах wifi AP.

Comment: прошивка последняя? мак отправителя в запросах совпадает с маком клиентов? есть фитча в каком то из режимах wifi, где маки подменяютя, толи wds толи client режим хотя не уверен что это есть и на этих точках. wds включен?

Comment: Стоит предпоследняя, есть последняя, но она бета и там исправлено только проблемы с SSH. Просто как я писал уже, я пробовал другой аппарат DIR-615 в режиме AP, та же история. Возможно это только d-link аппараты такие.

Comment: однако в моем случае все работало! да кстате аутентификация присутствует? ради теста можно попробовать без нее хотя будит ребут и все заработает ну это на подледок!Еще разок :мак отправителя в запросах совпадает с маком клиентов?

Comment: Проверил еще раз. И в запросе и в ответе данные корректные.

Comment: а DWL случаем не в HP ProCurve 2650 подкл? Тогда можно было бы на нем фильтровать dhcp , а на точке включить и таки образом dhcp друг другу не мешали и клиенты получали бы ip

Comment: Подключен в HP ProCurve 1800-24G. Я вот не пойму почему оно после перезагрузки AP работает.

Comment: По поводу аутентификации, эти клиенты работают без аутентификации, но у проводных клиентов она есть.

Comment: да кто его знает :) эти девайсы хорошо себя ведут в качестве моста с "тяжелым" линком, а в качестве офисной ап вечно проблемы. А через какое время перестают работать? Да кстате пришла в голову мысль что это не АП виноваты тк 615  тоже также себя видет думаю нужно капать в сторону свитча 1800-24G он 2го уровня на нем куча функций.

Comment: Перестает работать через пару дней точно, а может быть и на следующий день не работает тоже, уже и не помню.

Comment: Сниф запросов со стороны клиентов

Answer (score 3):

Вот как я представляю вашу ситуацию. На вашей точке доступа DHCP отключен и соответственно отбрасывает широковещательные запросы. То есть запросы к DHCP дальше вашей AP не идут. На некоторых маршрутизаторах есть так называемые агенты ретрансляции, в настройках это указывается как DHCP Relay. Имеет ли такую функцию ваша AP - сказать не могу. Как вариант - создать отдельный пул для wi-fi клиентов и на точке доступа продублировать привязку к MAC. Разумеется, DHCP в этом случае придется включить.

Comment: нет там wifi с eth бриджем совмещен так что не катит .DHCP Relay те DHCP forward он там не нужен. тк на вайфай другую подсеть поставить нельзя.

Comment: При подключении беспроводного клиента широковещательный запрос получает только точка доступа - и никто больше. Логическую сеть и не надо разбивать. Выделяете пул на вашем основном DHCP сервере для беспроводных клиентов, допустим 10.0.1.16-10.0.1.24 - чтобы никто не мог занять их адреса также делаем привязку по MAC. На точке доступа настраиваем DHCP на выдачу адресов из 10.0.1.16-10.0.1.24 и также привязываем к MAC. Бридж(сетевой мост, работает на сетевом уровне)в данном случае ни на что не влияет, поскольку работает уже с логической сетью, то есть ip-адресами, которых еще нет.

Comment: при подключение клиента запрос получает вся сеть включая тех кто сидит по проводу.У меня была похожая схема : в офисе был сервер на 2003 видне с dhcp и 2 dwl 2100ap естественно dhcp, на них был вырублен wifi клиенты получали ip с 2003 винды. Проблема у длинк данной модели всегда возникал с аутентификацией wpa2 но то была wep2, а тут немного другое.

Comment: Все может быть, с dwl-2100 дела не имел и спорить не стану. Может быть при выключенном DHCP агент ретрансляции и включается автоматически. Но мне попадались и такие точки, которые ни за что на свете не пропускали через себя широковещательный трафик, и такие которые требовали ручного включения такой функции. В принципе, такой функционал можно реализовать программно.

Comment: да там все просто два интерфейса совмещены brctl и все тупо мост между интерфейсами. Лочить трафик можно например iptables. На DWL фаервола нет

Answer (score 2):

Если не используется (или не критично использование) M$-мулька с передачей MSDHCP-сервером данных об клиентских IP в MSDNS домена (используется исключительно в серверах MS), то можно переложить обязанность раздачи клиентам адресов от DLink`а - логично предположить, что в такой реализации ситуация улучшится.Попробуйте - попытка не пытка.

Comment: Увы нужен именно описанный вариант.

Comment: тогда пробоват что сказал @sergarcada  У меня, в своевремя, DFL-210 раздавал IP, но для wifi клиентов выделил пул. wifi раздавал ZyXell P660EE. Косяков не было... Авторизация DHCP в домене нормально проходит?

Comment: Сделал чтобы AP сама раздавала IP, но история повторилась. Вчера IP получил на тестовые устройства и потом их выключил, а клиенты работали до конца дня. Сегодня клиенты продолжают работать без проблем, но тестовые устройства немогут получить IP.

Comment: Странная ситуация... А какие клиенты на тестовых устройствах? Сроки аренды на сервере? Стабильные клиенты получали адреса из отдельного пула? Стабильные клиенты тоже получали IP с АР? Отключено ли IPv6 на wifi-клиентах?